# How to make settings for smtp to be dynamic? i got an error Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Mail\MailManager::getConfig()

Tags: php, laravel, mailer

How to make settings for smtp to be dynamic? i got an error

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Mail\MailManager::getConfig() must be of the type string, null given, called in
```

I use this tutorial
https://kayike.medium.com/enable-unique-and-dynamic-smtp-mail-settings-for-each-user-laravel-48e320d381ec

this is my code in my service provider

```
$mailer = Setting::where('type', 'mail')->whereIn('key', ['host', 'port', 'username', 'password', 'encryption'])->get();
        $mailer = $mailer->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
            return [$item['key'] => $item['value']];
        });

        if (isset($mailer['host'])) {
            Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.host', $mailer['host']);
            Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.username', $mailer['username']);
            Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.password', $mailer['password']);
            Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.port', $mailer['port']);
            Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.encryption', $mailer['encryption']);

        }
```

and I created a new middleware file and the code is like this

```
 $app = App::getInstance();
        $app->register('App\Providers\MailServiceProvider');
        return $next($request);
```

please help me, I've been looking for a solution everywhere but can't find it